# Geany autocomplete Python constraints

Tags: python, autocomplete, geany

How can I get Geany to autocomplete an object's *constraints*?

For example, I type:

`self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_`

And I want the list of possible constraints to show up such as `WIN_POS_NONE` and `WIN_POS_CENTER` etc.

NOTE: CTRL+SPACE or CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE does not show constraints.

Autocompletion works fine for functions and symbols, just not constraints, unless I've used it once already before.  This saves me the time of looking at documentation.  Sometimes I can partially remember the constraint, and it would be nice to be able to browse the options.

I would basically like it to work like it does in Sublime Text, which is a near-perfect editor for me, but I'm looking for something free/opensource to use.

EDIT: I've also tried Ninja-IDE which can also display constraints, but it locks up sometimes and is not as lightweight as Geany...

EDIT 2: I'm not looking for an alternative to Geany, I'm looking to make this functionality work via a mod or plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have been able to find, this is beyond what Geany can do.  I asked how to get Geany to do this and I am not looking for any alternatives to Geany, nor am I interested in using anything else.  Therefore, this is the accepted answer, unless someone posts a way to make it work in Geany, at that point I will change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think *Geany* is capable of doing this. But [*PyCharm*](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is a lot better IDE for Python. It knows everything about your code, and also has an intelligent code completion, on-the-fly error checking and quick-fixes, easy project navigation, and much more.

There is also a [free version ready to download](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) which contains more than enough functionality a common programmer may need.

Comment: I have tried PyCharm, but I'm not a fan of how it work.  Like I said, Ninja-IDE is good, except for the freezing part.  All I really want is to be able to have the functionality of showing constraints in Geany because I like it, and it's very lightweight.  That's really the only part missing.

Answer (score 0):

go to preferences:

[image]

check autocompletes you want.

[image]